# Specific doubts on kgp.py program in dive into python book

Tags: python, xml

[Dive into Python: XML Processing](http://linux.die.net/diveintopython/html/xml_processing/parsing_xml.html#kgp.divein) -

Here I am referring to a portion of `kgp.py` program -

```
def getDefaultSource(self):
  xrefs = {}
  for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref"):
    xrefs[xref.attributes["id"].value] = 1
  xrefs = xrefs.keys()
  standaloneXrefs = [e for e in self.refs.keys() if e not in xrefs]
  if not standaloneXrefs:
    raise NoSourceError, "can't guess source, and no source specified"
  return '<xref id="%s"/>' % random.choice(standaloneXrefs)
```

`self.grammar:` parsed `XML` representation (`using xml.dom.minidom`) of -

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<grammar>
<ref id="bit">
  <p>0</p>
  <p>1</p>
</ref>
<ref id="byte">
  <p><xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/>\
<xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/><xref id="bit"/></p>
</ref>
</grammar>
```

`self.refs:` is the caching of all the `refs` of the above `XML` key'd by their `id`

---

I have two doubts with this code:

**Doubt 1:**

```
  for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref"):
    xrefs[xref.attributes["id"].value] = 1
  xrefs = xrefs.keys()
```

eventaully `xrefs` holds the id values in a list. Couldn't we have done this simply by -

```
  xrefs = [xref.attributes["id"].value 
           for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref")]
```

---

**Doubt 2:**

```
  standaloneXrefs = [e for e in self.refs.keys() if e not in xrefs]
  ...
  return '<xref id="%s"/>' % random.choice(standaloneXrefs)
```

Here, we are saving the `ref` from `self.refs` which we do NOT see in our computed `xrefs`. But next instead of creating a `<ref>` element, we are creating a `<xref>` with the same ID. This takes us one step backward, since later we are anyway going to find the cross reference for this computed `<xref>` and eventually reach the `<ref>`. We could have just started with this `<ref>` in the first place.

---

### Disclaimer

I am in no way trying to make a remark on the book. I am not even qualified for that.

I am loving every moment of reading this book. I realize few chapters have gone [outdated](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/8miar/im_new_to_python_should_i_read_dive_into_python_3/c09s45y?context=3), but I love [Mark Pilgrim's](http://diveintomark.org/) writing style and I cannot stop reading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Dive Into Python*](http://diveintopython.net/index.html) is seven years old now (published 2004), and doesn't always contain the most modern code. So you need to go easy on it: [*Dive Into Python 3*](http://diveintopython3.net/xml.html) might be a better bet.

Your suggestion for doubt 1 changes the meaning of the code: putting the ids into the keys of a dictionary and then getting them out again eliminates duplicates, whereas your list comprehension includes duplicates. The modern approach would be to use a *set comprehension*:

```
 xrefs = {xref.attributes["id"].value 
          for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref")}
```

but this wasn't available in 2004.

On your doubt 2, I'm not entirely sure I see the problem. Yes, in some sense this is a waste, but on the other hand the code already has a handler for the `xref` case, so it makes sense to re-use that handler rather than add an extra special case.

There are several other bits of code in that example that could be modernized. For example,

```
source and source or self.getDefaultSource()
```

would now be `source or self.getDefaultSource()`. And the line

```
standaloneXrefs = [e for e in self.refs.keys() if e not in xrefs]
```

would be better expressed as a set difference operation, something like:

```
standaloneXrefs = set(self.refs) - set(xrefs)
```

But that's what happens as languages become more expressive: old code starts to look rather inelegant.

Comment: oh yes! I didn't realize that. However since we are saving the `<ref>` by their `ids` wouldn't it be safe to assume the resulting list would have NO duplicates? (unless otherwise our input XML itself is flawed)

Comment: Yes, I guess so: if the XML has parsed, it must be well-formed, and so the ids must be distinct. So you could safely use a list comprehension here. (But since both Mark Pilgrim and I missed this point, it's probably sufficiently non-obvious that it's worth a comment.)

Comment: But on further investigation, it seems that `xml.dom.minidom` doesn't actually check this aspect of the well-formedness of the input, so I think enforcing the uniqueness of ids is a justifiable precaution.

Comment: am I making a mistake learning python from such an old book? I am loving it as for now, but it seems it is kind of dated now. Would love to hear some suggestions on python programming for programmers? (I had in mind to read `Python Cookbook` by Alex next)

Comment: No, I think you'll be fine, as long as you bear in mind that some of the advice may be out of date. Have you read the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)? The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/index.html)?

Answer (score 1):

```
for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref"):
  xrefs[xref.attributes["id"].value] = 1
xrefs = xrefs.keys()
```

This is an extremely crude way to construct a set. This should be written as

```
set(xref.attributes["id"].value
    for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref"))
```

or even (in [Python 2.7+](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)):

```
{xref.attributes["id"].value
 for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref")) }
```

If avoiding duplicates is not an issue, your solution (constructing a list) works too. Since xref is iterated over anyway, one could even generate an iterator.

---

```
standaloneXrefs = [e for e in self.refs.keys() if e not in xrefs]
...
return '<xref id="%s"/>' % random.choice(standaloneXrefs)
```

This code is completely broken if xref contains a special character such as `"` or `&`.
However, in principle, it is correct to construct an `<xref>` element here, since this must be the same format that the external `source` has (`getDefaultSource` is called as

```
self.loadSource(source and source or self.getDefaultSource())
```

).

---

Both code excerpts are examples of bad programming and should not be included in a book that intends to teach people how to program. Dive Into Python3 has [better XML examples and code](http://diveintopython3.org/xml.html).

Comment: Re your last concern: `id`s in XML are [constrained to contain only certain characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#id), so this can't happen.

Comment: @Gareth Rees Yes, but that would be assuming the input is valid XML. Since IDs must also be unique, constructing a set would not be necessary if the validity of the input was somehow guaranteed.

Comment: "...since this must be the same format that the external source has": hmm? I am not able to understand this requirement. How is returning `<xref ...>` returning the same format and returning `<ref ...>` is not? and why is there a format requirement anyway?

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajpai If `source` is set, it is used instead of the result of this method. Therefore, this method must match the format of `source`. If you'd generate `<ref>`s, you'd have to change the calling code.

Comment: On further investigation, I see that `xml.dom.minidom` does not check for well-formedness of ids. So your criticism is fair.

Comment: @phihag: but the `source` is set from the command line, so there isn't any requirement in the code snippet as to what format can or cannot the source be (it just should be parseable by `xml.dom.minidom`)

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajpai If you specify `<ref ..>` in the source, the program doesn't work as intended since there's no `do_ref` method. Bear in mind the whole program is an example of how *not* to write XML code. Nowaydays, you should really build an etree (possibly with [lxml](http://lxml.de/)) and use an xpath expression to match the nodes you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts are totally justified: that code doesn't look very good to me at all. For example, it uses `1` as a boolean value where `True` would have sufficed and been clearer.

#### Doubt 1:

These two snippets don't do the same. If there are duplicates, the original code will filter them out, but your alternative won't. On the other hand, your code preserves the original ordering whereas the original returns the elements in an arbitrary order.

To be fully equivalent, we could use the `set` builtin:

xrefs = list(set([xref.attributes["id"].value 
                    for xref in self.grammar.getElementsByTagName("xref")]))

(It might not make sense to convert back to a list, though.)

#### Doubt 2:

Out of time, gotta run, sorry...